# Microsoft Edge: where to manually set registry settings for policy testing?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-edge

For Chrome on Windows enterprise policies can manually be set in this registry folder:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome
```

For the new Chromium-based Edge where is the registry folder?

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge
```

The current set of Microsoft Edge Policies are here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies

Comment: You have to manually create that registry path containing Edge.

Answer (score 0):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]

Answer (score 0):

On my computer there are Group Policies applying to Edge (Chromium) and I have registry keys for these policies showing up under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Edge`.

I would guess that if you're testing by manually creating registry keys:

1. You may need to create that key first
2. You should probably just use the local group policy editor as this will be easier and less prone to errors. Once you've applied policies this way and confirmed their function, you can copy the registry keys that were created and apply those to other systems if that is what you want to do.